# How do you set the price of a new Coin at the beginning?

Tags: exchange-rate, altcoin-development

When starting a new coin, how do you know what to set the initial value of the coin?

Can you set it at something like 1.00 if not listed on a exchange?

The people of this coin will only be trading it for a year before they start to sell it at market value.

Just need to know how to put an initial value for the coin

Answer (score 1):

If the coin relies on a decentralized proof of work based blockchain like Bitcoin the price is set by the free market (supply and demand).

If coin issuance is centrally controlled because of a premine by the issuer, then the controlling entity will have more control. There are many different ways to structure ICOs each with different economic, security and legal considerations. If you are the coin issuer referenced in this question you will need to answer these questions on your own or be more specific in describing your question(s).

Comment: Yes I am the coin owner.   There is a good deal of premine.   With that said, I can set my own price based on what people will pay for the coin correct?   Is this a common practice that has been done before?  and if so, at a later time can I take it and have it listed on a exchange?

Comment: You cannot control the price. It's set by the market. If nobody wants to buy, the price will be zero.